# Python3: How to print elements of a list where list name is an element in another list?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I'm a beginner with python and am attempting to write a script that will save the location of a server in a list, and then populate a separate list named after the location with the server names.  I can't figure out how to loop through thee data in my first list, and use the resulting value to loop through the data in the second list.

The location is encoded in the FQDN of the server, and is being stripped out via REGEX.

For example:

```py
locations = ["austx", "chntx", "santx"]

austx = ["aus.1", "aus.2", "aus.3"]

chntx = ["chn.1", "chn.2", "chn.3"]

santx = ["sat.1", "sat.2", "sat.3"]

for i in locations:
    print(i)
```

The above code will get me my locations.  How can I then automatically loop through the austx list when austx is the i value in the original locations loop?

I feel like this should be simple but I'm missing something here...

Comment: Maybe a map/dictionary would be more convenient?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use for [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
locations = ["austx", "chntx", "santx"]

austx = ["aus.1", "aus.2", "aus.3"]

chntx = ["chn.1", "chn.2", "chn.3"]

santx = ["sat.1", "sat.2", "sat.3"]

for i in zip(locations, [austx, chntx, santx]):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
('austx', ['aus.1', 'aus.2', 'aus.3'])
('chntx', ['chn.1', 'chn.2', 'chn.3'])
('santx', ['sat.1', 'sat.2', 'sat.3'])
```

Sometimes a one-to-one relationship between two datatypes suggests an opportunity to zip them together.

Comment: This initially sounds like a great idea, but since my location values are being programmatically defined (I'm trying really hard not to maintain lists here) I can't easily define a list for a location without using a dictionary type structure already I believe.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, as this would be a simple way to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want a different data structure for this.  Rather than seperate lists, you probably want a list of lists, so that what you actually have is:

```
locations = [["aus.1", "aus.2", "aus.3"],
             ["chn.1", "chn.2", "chn.3"],
             ["sat.1", "sat.2", "sat.3"]]
```

Then you can iterate through like so:

```
for i in locations:
    for val in i:
        print(val)
```

Otherwise if you need to keep the names for some other reason, you can have your other lists in a dictionary separate to your main list:

```
locations = ["austx", "chntx", "santx"]
lists = {"austx": ["aus.1", "aus.2", "aus.3"],
         "chntx": ["chn.1", "chn.2", "chn.3"],
         "santx": ["sat.1", "sat.2", "sat.3"]}
```

Then look up like:

```
for i in locations:
    lst = lists[i]
    for val in lst:
        print(val)
```

Comment: And I didn't want to mention this as part of the answer, because you shouldn't do it, but you _can_ get access to your local scope as a dictionary using `locals()`.  This lets you do `for i in locations: lst = locals()[i]`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot simplify my script like in your first example because I need the location data separate from the server data.  Essentially I need to gather the locations for the servers, then print out a table of what servers exist in what location.

Your second option looks like lists is a dictionary pointing to a list...  This is pretty much exactly what I need!  Now, I need to just figure out how to get the data into that sort of structure...

Comment: Then you should be using the second example and put your lists into a dictionary.  If you can't figure out how to do that, you might need to make a new question and show the code which creates the lists.

Comment: It looks like my Achilles heel here is that I need to programmatically create the dictionary key, and somehow point it to a list that I can update.

Comment: It turns out the solution was to do this:

locationdict.setdefault(location, []).append(hostname)

This creates the 2nd data structure you mentioned above and allows me to move on.  Thank you again for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in order to create the Dictionary - List type structure needed.

dictionary.setdefault(location, []).append(hostname)

The structure of that dictionary is such:

dictionary = {"austx": ["aus.1", "aus.2", "aus.3"], "chntx": ["chn.1", "chn.2", "chn.3"], "santx": ["sat.1", "sat.2", "sat.3"]}